# Flutter Container not expanding to fit content

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the code below that I'm using to create a listview

```
 Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, PostListModel postList){
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,   
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
         Expanded( 
         
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children:  <Widget> [
                PentEmotionWidget(iconid:  postList.iconID),
                Text(
                    postList.post, 
                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  )    
              
              ],
            )  ,
        
         ),

        ],
     ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _latestPosts.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemExtent: 80,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
        _buildListItem(context, _latestPosts[index]),   
      );
  }
```

This is how it ends up looking

[image]

So basically the holding container isn't expanding to fit the content. I've tried experimenting with Flexible and Expanded, doesn't make a difference. Anyone has an idea of whats wrong?

Comment: You want to red emoji is same line as your text?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes

Comment: check below answer, I have try using `ListTile` ans `Row` widgets

Answer (score 1):

You can used [**`ListTile`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) Widget also, refer below code

#### Using ListTile

```
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.emoji_emotions,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    title: Text('This is a test'),
  ),
),
```

#### Using Row

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Icon(
        Icons.emoji_emotions,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text('This is a test'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the cross-axis alignment to center

```
         child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children:  <Widget> [
                Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined),
                Text(
                  "This is test",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Result ==> [image]